# Error: Class 'TwitterOAuth\Config' not found

Tags: twitter-oauth

Script:

require "abraham/twitteroauth/Config.php";
require "abraham/twitteroauth/TwitterOAuth.php";

Error:

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'TwitterOAuth\Config' not found in /Users/robertseymour/MacBook_Local/scripts/abraham/twitteroauth/TwitterOAuth.php:33

---

require "abraham/twitteroauth/Config.php";

print_r(get_declared_classes());

Output:

[184] => Abraham\TwitterOAuth\Config

### Loads OK.

Any idea why Class 'TwitterOAuth\Config' not found?
Am I missing something the namespace?

Thanks!
Robert

---

Changed TwitterOAuth.php namespace to:

Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth

Now:

$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $access_token, $access_token_secret);

Returns:

Uncaught Error:Class 'TwitterOAuth' not found in /Users/robertseymour/MacBook_Local/scripts/twitter2.php on line 10

print_r(get_declared_classes());

[184] => Abraham\TwitterOAuth\Config

[185] => Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth

### Both classes loaded OK.

Changed twitteraouth.php namespace to:

namespace Abraham\TwitterOAuth;

Now:

```
public function resetLastResponse(): void{
  $this->response = new Response();
}
```

Uncaught Error: Class 'TwitterOAuth\Response' not found